# Alertmanager email notification not working

Tags: prometheus, slack, email-notifications, prometheus-alertmanager

I have the below `alertmanager.yml` to send the alerts to Mail and Slack channel. Here i am getting alerts on slack, But i am not getting email alerts same time while getting in slack. There is no error shown in my alert-manager container log.

```
global:
  resolve_timeout: 5m
  smtp_smarthost: 'smtp.server.com:25'
  smtp_from: 'user@company.com'
  http_config:
    tls_config:
      insecure_skip_verify: true
      
route:
  group_wait: 10s
  group_interval: 30s
  repeat_interval: 30m

  # A default receiver
  receiver: "email"

  # All the above attributes are inherited by all child routes and can
  # overwritten on each.
  routes:
    - receiver: "slack"
      group_wait: 10s
      match_re:
        severity: critical|warning
      continue: true

    - receiver: "email"
      group_wait: 10s
      match_re:
        severity: critial
      continue: true

receivers:
  - name: "slack"
    slack_configs:
      - api_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/XXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXX/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        send_resolved: true
        channel: '#monitoring'
        text: "{{ range .Alerts }}<!channel> {{ .Annotations.summary }}\n{{ .Annotations.description }}\n{{ end }}"

  - name: "email"
    email_configs:
      - to: 'reciever@company.com'
        send_resolved: true
        auth_username: 'user@company.com'
        auth_identity: 'user@company.com'
        auth_password: 'password'
```

However email alone configuration as per this link [Mail notification](https://github.com/shazforiot/Prometheusalertmanager/blob/main/email_alertmanager.yml) works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an alert matches the first route it won't be sent to the second route.

Use the [Routing tree editor](https://www.prometheus.io/webtools/alerting/routing-tree-editor/) to visualize the routing tree.

Note: there's a typo in the "severity: critial" line.

Comment: thanks Marcelo.i have fixed with the help of `https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2019/05/17/install-alertmanager-to-alert-based-on-metrics-from-prometheus/`